# C# code for writing data to OpenTSDB

Tags: c#, sockets, opentsdb

A (sort of - it's not directly to do with C#) related question in SO is: [How to insert data in OpenTSDB (Time Series Database)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8520612/how-to-insert-data-in-opentsdb-time-series-database-from-client); as mentioned there, the basic shell command which easily works (in linux) is as follows:

```
echo "put mymetric.data_1 1295643636 48 a=foo" | nc -w 15 tsdHost tsdPort
```

My question is has anyone written a collector in C# for OpenTSDB? The issue I am facing is that although I can open a Socket to the tsd instance/port and I write the following to its stream, nothing seems to happen.

```
put mymetric.data_1 1295643636 48 a=foo
```

I am creating an InterNetwork, Stream based TCP Socket, and tried sending the above string as ASCII, UTF-8,-16 and -32 encoded bytes, all in vain.

Any pointers in what kind of Socket and what kind of encoded bytes I need to use will really help. The `Java` code sample for the same thing I am trying to achieve is:

```
Socket sock = new Socket("tsd.server.com", 4242); 
String point = "put my.metric 1314137008 60 host=someplace.net foo=1\n"; 
sock.getOutputStream().write(point.getBytes()); 
sock.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized the string that I was sending did not have the newline character at the end. In the Java code sample, the newline is there explicitly.

Adding a newline at the end resolved the problem.

Sample code where you add the newline explicitly:

```
string message = "put mymetric.data_1 1295643636 48 a=foo";
IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"); // tsdb deamon host ip
IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(ip, 4242); // tsdb deamon port

using (Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp))
{
    s.Connect(endPoint);
    s.Send(new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(message + Environment.NewLine));
    s.Close();  
}
```